# Notetaking with Latex and collapsing text for research papers

Tags: software, note-taking

I am looking for a note-taking software with the following features,
I would appreciate any advice!

- Collapsing or folding text (Like FoldingText or other outliners)
- Ability to quickly write up formulas (Like stack exchange's Markdown)
- Relatively pretty
- Nice writing experience
- Hopefully cheap

This would be helpful while taking notes from research publications side it is highly unwieldy to have a sparse collection of text files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia.  (This site is for questions about academia itself, rather than software that could be useful in academia.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: It may be so (under strict perception). But I don't this deserves to be closed either. The specified tags do fit well in Academia.SE and the question itself doesn't seem to be in the 'do not ask about' section.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Emacs/[org-mode](http://orgmode.org/). Advantage: It is a simple yet powerful (and in principle infitely extendable) plain-text outliner with all the features that you require. Disadvantage: It requires some familiarity with the Emacs-editor, which has a relatively steep learning-curve.